# Get backup folder information using Google drive api

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api

Is there any way to get Google drive backup folder information or the time when android device apps where last backed up?
I am making an android app which checks the last backup time

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the backups are saved into an application data folder, an special hidden folder that saves application-specific files. Every application has one and can only be accessed by it. This means that you won't be able to access it with your application.

### References

- [Store application-specific data (Google Drive API v3 guide)](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/appdata)